# Unable to set Fontfamily

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uilabel

I am using `fontscore.com_h_helvetica-neue-lt-std-75-bold.otf` to set `UILabel` font.

I have already added this font in `.plist`, but i am unable to set this font family.

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
  NSLog(@"%f",self.font.pointSize);
  [super awakeFromNib];
  self.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
  [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontscore.com_h_helvetica-neue-lt-std-75-bold"   size:self.font.pointSize]];
}
```

Can you guys please help me in understanding what is the issue?

Comment: I'll get UIFont is searching for a font bundle with the extension `com_h_helvetica-neue-lt-std-75-bold`.  That really is an unfortunate name for a font, you'll need to change it

Comment: what should be the name?please suggest me.

Comment: I am using customfont HelveticaNeueLTStd-75bold.otf but its not applying.

Answer (score 1):

The font family name isn't always the actual filename, you can enumerate the available fonts to find out the actually family names available like so.

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"Font family: %@", familyName);
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"Font: %@", fontName);
    }
}
```